# Promises in Javascipt does not make execut the loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I had this piece of code in Javascript

```
if(!this.top3){
    const promises = this.images.map((el, index) => {
      return this.getData(el.title, index);
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      this.getUnknown();
      this.$emit("onTaskFinished");
      //this.showResults = true
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

`This.images` is an Array the contanins names of images in `title` and `data` is empty.

Now I need to change the function because `this.images` will become an Array containing group of images. Each group is an Array, each one contains the images in `data` and names of images in `title`.

So I changed the function in this way:

```
var j=0;
 for(j=0; j<this.images.length; j++){
      this.imgIndex = j;
       const promises = this.images[j].title.map((el, index) => {
            return this.getData(el, index);
       })

       return Promise.all(promises)
       .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
       
        this.getUnknown();
        this.$emit("onTaskFinished");
  }
```

In this way it does not work because the `for` loop is executed only 1 time.

I think that the problem is `Promises` because if i remove it, the program remain for ever in the loop.
I'm new using `Javascript` so I know I'm doing some mistakes.

EDIT

Sorry, of course there is a `j++` inside the for loop.

I'll give you more information. As I said, in the old code, in `this.images.title` there are titles of images.

For each image,in `this.getData()` I call an API to back-end giving him the title and obtaining the image.Then I put it in `this.image[i].data`:

```
async getData(img_name, i) {
      await this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserProfile");
      return this.axios
        .get(
          process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API + `/getResults/${encodeURIComponent(img_name)}?experiment=${this.experiment}`,
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "image/jpeg",
              Authorization: "Bearer " + this.$store.state.userProfile,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("res: ", res);
          if (res.status == 400) {
            this.$router.push("/login");
            alert("SESSION EXPIRED. PLEASE LOG-IN AGAIN.");
            throw Error("TOKEN EXPIRED");
          } else {
              if(!this.top3){
                  let blob = new Blob([res.data], {
                    type: res.headers["content-type"],
                  });
                  this.images[i].data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

Obviously I also changed `this.getData()` in order to put the response in the correct place, so I replaced `this.images[i].data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);` with `this.images[this.imgIndex].data.push(URL.createObjectURL(blob))`

It works but, as I said, only for the first element, then it blocks.

Comment: Did you mean `j++`? Even with that, the `return` in the loop body is just going to stop on the first iteration and the two lines starting with `this.getUnknown();` are unreachable. It's a bit hard to follow the code and infer your intent without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the question adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use return in the loop. Using return stopping the loop after the first iteration.

```
for(var j=0; j<this.images.length; j){

      this.imgIndex = j;
       const promises = this.images[j].title.map((el, index) => {
            return this.getData(el, index);
       })

       await Promise.all(promises)
       .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
       
        this.getUnknown();
        this.$emit("onTaskFinished");
        j++;
  }
```

Comment: This is still an infinite loop... Also, maybe OP wants to return something. It's unclear.

Comment: @ggorlen you are correct. j++ is required. I didn't notice his absence

Comment: We can use await in for a loop when the loop in the async function.

Comment: As we have mentioned, return blocks the loob after the first iteration.